# compute engine sql shared with app engine

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

what is the best method of sharing SQL server running on my compute engine (debian) with app engine?

I've tried creating a firewall policy to allow all connection from tcp:3306 but it's not working. The port still seems to remain blocked. I don't feel comfortable opening up this port anyways so maybe there are alternative ways to do this that is more secure?

so its actually two questions
why am i unable to open port 3306 and what is a better way of allowing SQL connection from app engine to compute engine
:)

Comment: you can't do it (easily) as app engine only speaks http. Just create an google cloud sql instance and use that. https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs

Answer (score 2):

There are several options open to you:

1. You could use [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/), which has specific ACL options for App Engine.
2. You can open the port... you must ensure:

   - GCE's [firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#addingafirewall) allows 3306,
   - your GCE instance [guest OS firewall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) allows port 3306,
   - MySQL is [configured to listen on the 0.0.0.0 address](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address) and
   - MySQL is not configured with [skip-networking](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking)

   I recommend you test this from your own workstation as well as from App Engine. This uses the socket API from Google App Engine, and so requires you have billing enabled.
3. Or you could switch to using the [App Engine Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/). This has the advantage that it will scale much better than MySQL, and does not have a single point of failure.

Comment: I am getting OperationalError: (2004, "Can't create TCP/IP socket (-1)") error while connecting mysql server (on compute engine) from app engine. Any ideas ?